Yocto recipe to clean and build other recipes
I have 4 recipe files, each one of which will build a specific application required for our project. Now I need to create a master recipe to clean and build all application recipes in a single command.
For example
I have 3 recipe files called A.bb, B.bb and C.bb. Each one of them is responsible for fetching and building a specific application. Now I need to create master.bb files that cleans and builds A.bb, B.bb and C.bb recipe files.

You may achieve this with below experiment.
Block master recipe until a particular task from the dependent recipe is done

First to cleanall before fetching in individual recipe files
do_fetch[depends] += "recipeA:do_cleanall"  --> In recipeA
do_fetch[depends] += "recipeB:do_cleanall"  --> In recipeB
do_fetch[depends] += "recipeC:do_cleanall"  --> In recipeC

In master recipe
do_compile[depends] += "recipeA:do_package"
do_compile[depends] += "recipeB:do_package"
do_compile[depends] += "recipeC:do_package"


By this way before compilation of master recipe it will complete packaging of all the other recipes and in individual recipes they will get clean before build starts.
Refer : https://docs.yoctoproject.org/1.6/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html#inter-task-dependencies
